# Finding multiple modes in a tuple list - python

Tags: python, tuples, mode, median

I am new in python and needed some help in finding out the mode of a tuple. However, the code I have right now only displays one mode, what would I need to change to display multiple modes (if the list of numbers has more than 1)

```
    import itertools
    import operator

    def mode_function2(lst):
       return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

Comment: What would you want `lst = [1,1,2,2]` to return?  `[1,2]` or `[1,1,2,2]`?  (I'm assuming the first.)  IOW, are you more interested in the identity of the modes or do you need their mulitplicity too?

Comment: sorry, "1st" isnt a good variable name to use. I actually have a different tuple which has alot of numbers and I just want to know WHICH number(s) occurs the most in the tuple so I guess identity. Right now it brings me only one number when there possibly could be more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
from collections import Counter
def mode_function2(lst):
    counter = Counter(lst)
    _,val = counter.most_common(1)[0]
    return [x for x,y in counter.items() if y == val]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> mode_function2([1, 2, 2])
[2]
>>> mode_function2([1, 2, 2, 1])
[1, 2]
>>> mode_function2([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The important concepts here are:

- [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its [`most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method
- A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def mode_function2(lst, multiplicity = False):
    maxFreq =  max(map(lst.count, lst))
    modes = [i for i in lst if lst.count(i) == maxFreq]
    return modes if multiplicity else set(modes)
```